# org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferException: Transport does not, or is not configured to, support state transfer

Tags: java, jboss, infinispan, change-notification

I have JBoss 5 and JBoss 7 running  in parallel in the same box using the same database. Plus I have Java database change notification and Infinispan configured. But while trying to start the application in JBoss7 without temporarily bring down JBoss 5 I get the below error in JBoss 7. Please advice on how do I overcome this

```
2017.04.06 10:09:46 INFO  GlobalComponentRegistry(691): Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Ursus' 4.2.1.FINAL
2017.04.06 10:09:46 INFO  GlobalComponentRegistry(691): Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Ursus' 4.2.1.FINAL
2017.04.06 10:09:46 DEBUG InterceptorChain(67): Interceptor chain size: 6
2017.04.06 10:09:46 DEBUG InterceptorChain(67): Interceptor chain size: 6
2017.04.06 10:09:46 DEBUG InterceptorChain(68): Interceptor chain is:
        >> org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor
        >> org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor
        >> org.infinispan.interceptors.NotificationInterceptor
        >> org.infinispan.interceptors.LockingInterceptor
        >> org.infinispan.interceptors.ReplicationInterceptor
        >> org.infinispan.interceptors.CallInterceptor
2017.04.06 10:09:46 DEBUG InterceptorChain(68): Interceptor chain is:
        >> org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor
        >> org.infinispan.interceptors.TxInterceptor
        >> org.infinispan.interceptors.NotificationInterceptor
        >> org.infinispan.interceptors.LockingInterceptor
        >> org.infinispan.interceptors.ReplicationInterceptor
        >> org.infinispan.interceptors.CallInterceptor
2017.04.06 10:09:46 DEBUG StateTransferManagerImpl(126): Initiating state transfer process
2017.04.06 10:09:46 DEBUG StateTransferManagerImpl(126): Initiating state transfer process
2017.04.06 10:09:46 WARN  JGroupsTransport(359): Channel not set up properly!
2017.04.06 10:09:46 ERROR CacheManager(444): Exception while trying to take over listening
org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.start() throws org.infinispan.statet
ransfer.StateTransferException on object
        at org.infinispan.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:174)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:889)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:687)
        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:589)
        at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.start(ComponentRegistry.java:147)
        at org.infinispan.CacheDelegate.start(CacheDelegate.java:323)
        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:516)
        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:439)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.infinispan.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:171)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferException: Transport does not, or is not configured to, support state transfer.  Please disable fetching
 state on startup, or reconfigure your transport.
        at org.infinispan.remoting.rpc.RpcManagerImpl.retrieveState(RpcManagerImpl.java:189)
        at org.infinispan.statetransfer.StateTransferManagerImpl.start(StateTransferManagerImpl.java:130)
        ... 22 more
```

Comment: Please crosslink with JBoss forums next time: https://developer.jboss.org/message/970623

Comment: I am afraid that many have forgotten details about almost 6 years old version.

Answer (score 0):

needed to update the initial member to 4 from 2 to take into account the additional set of clusters, instance. 
num_initial_members="${jgroups.num.initial.members:2}"

Detailed xml config : developer.jboss.org/message/970623